# Weight difference in excercise for same muscle

Tags: exercise, strength, muscle

I wanted to workout by posterior delts, so I was doing revese chest fly on machine and I was able to do it with 80 pounds, but when Dumbbell Bent-Over Reverse Fly i am doing i can take only 10 pounds of dumbbell, why such a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can help, i came across it the other day when i had the exact same question. https://breakingmuscle.com/fitness/why-the-numbers-on-weight-machines-are-a-lie

Comment: Can't agree, though partiality true. I think my other muscles are helping

Comment: Good answer, but instead of just posting a link, it would be helpful if you could post text out of the answer, that way if the page is taken down in the future, people will still be able to use this answer

Comment: @murmansk I used to train at a pretty hard core powerlifting gym, while there, I noticed that I could do tricep pulldowns with more weight on one cable machine than the other. I asked the gym owner about it, and he said it's because one machine uses an extra pulley, so there is a greater mechanical advantage, so it takes less work to move the same weight.